# Django (DRF) & React - Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set)

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, csrf

There are tens of questions that are essentially identical to the one I'm asking. However, none of their answers seem to be working for me.

I have a React front-end where I am using `axios` to send requests to the back-end. Example
`const request = await axios.post('${BASE_URL}/logout/')`

Most of the Django Rest Framework endpoints are made with ViewSets. However, I have a few that are custom and mostly made for authentication.

```
path('createaccount/', views.create_account),
path('me/', views.current_user),
path('logout/', views.logout),
path('login/', views.login),
path('resetpassword', views.reset_password),
```

For the development of this project I've included `@csrf_exempt` above these views because I didn't want to deal with it at the time. Now I'm nearing deployment and it's time to figure it out.

Some answers say I need to get a CSRF Token from Django which is stored in cookies and I need to pass that in the header of each request. Some answers say all I need to do is configure axios like

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "XCSRF-TOKEN";
```

And it will "just work". I've tried adjusting my `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME` to various values to get this to work too.

Some answers even say to keep `@csrf_exempt` but that sounds like a very, very bad idea.

Do I actually need to generate/get a CSRF cookie? Do I include it with every request? Or is it just a configuration of axios?

Comment: What authentication mechanism you're using? If it's session then yes you need to include `CSRF` in every `(POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE)` If so then try this to get the https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/ token from cookie and then make the request.

Comment: I'm using JWT token authentication.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem? It seems I've ran into a very similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

To make CSRF protection work you will need CSRF cookie sent from Django to
React as a response to some request (like login or sth else). It will set cookie using
Set-Cookie on frontend side. So make sure that you have a view that does that on Django side. If not, create a view that as response generates that token.

How Django (4.04) CSRF validation work (simplified, based on middleware/csrf.py):

1. gets CSRF token from cookie (so frontend needs to resend it back on
   another request) - it might also get it from session but in case of
   React I would not use it

   ```
   def _get_token(self, request):
       ....
       try:
           cookie_token = request.COOKIES[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME]
       except KeyError:
           return None
   ```
2. Compares that cookie CSRF token with non-cookie token from request:

   ```
   def _check_token(self, request):
       # Access csrf_token via self._get_token() as rotate_token() may have
       # been called by an authentication middleware during the
       # process_request() phase.
       try:
           csrf_token = self._get_token(request)
       except InvalidTokenFormat as exc:
           raise RejectRequest(f"CSRF cookie {exc.reason}.")

       if csrf_token is None:
           # No CSRF cookie. For POST requests, we insist on a CSRF cookie,
           # and in this way we can avoid all CSRF attacks, including login
           # CSRF.
           raise RejectRequest(REASON_NO_CSRF_COOKIE)

       # Check non-cookie token for match.
       request_csrf_token = ""
       if request.method == "POST":
           try:
               request_csrf_token = request.POST.get("csrfmiddlewaretoken", "")
           except UnreadablePostError:
               # Handle a broken connection before we've completed reading the
               # POST data. process_view shouldn't raise any exceptions, so
               # we'll ignore and serve the user a 403 (assuming they're still
               # listening, which they probably aren't because of the error).
               pass

       if request_csrf_token == "":
           # Fall back to X-CSRFToken, to make things easier for AJAX, and
           # possible for PUT/DELETE.
           try:
               request_csrf_token = request.META[settings.CSRF_HEADER_NAME]
           except KeyError:
               raise RejectRequest(REASON_CSRF_TOKEN_MISSING)
           token_source = settings.CSRF_HEADER_NAME
       else:
           token_source = "POST"

       try:
           request_csrf_token = _sanitize_token(request_csrf_token)
       except InvalidTokenFormat as exc:
           reason = self._bad_token_message(exc.reason, token_source)
           raise RejectRequest(reason)

       if not _does_token_match(request_csrf_token, csrf_token):
           reason = self._bad_token_message("incorrect", token_source)
           raise RejectRequest(reason)
   ```

As you can see you either need to include `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in POST request or include it in header with key: `settings.CSRF_HEADER_NAME` and value read from cookies on front-end side.

So for example you set `withCredentials: true` (to include initial cookie), read that initial CSRF cookie in React and add to header in axios request at specific key.

When in question, I would just debug request setting up breakpoints in this code of Django in middleware/csrf.py and you can trace what is missing and why CSRF validation fails.

Answer (score -1):

I've got this problem once, I was using token authentication. That's how I solved it. But not sure If it is the best idea. I only used csrf_exempt for this view and all others views are viewsets.

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_current_user(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user
        serializer = UserDataSerializer(user)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

My middleware in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
   # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   'auditlog.middleware.AuditlogMiddleware',
]
```